# Can not bind to Mono<String> via @PathVariable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I am following the code from Simon Basle's 'Reactor by Example' using spring boot 2.0.0.M2.  It works like a charm.  However when I tried to bind the path variable to Mono and send the request http://localhost:8080/monohello/Hero, it responded as below:

> {
>     "timestamp": 1500534277626,
>     "status": 500,
>     "error": "Internal Server Error",
>     "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono': no matching editors or conversion strategy found",
>     "path": "/monohello/Hero"
>   }

Below is the controller:

```
@RestController public class ExampleController {

@GetMapping("hello/{who}")
public Mono<String> hello(@PathVariable String who) {
    return Mono.just(who).map(w -> "Hello " + w + "!");
}

@GetMapping("monohello/{who}")
public Mono<String> monoHello(@PathVariable Mono<String> who) {
    return who.map(w -> "Hello " + w + "!");
}}
```

Comment: have you tried ex : `@GetMapping("/monohello/{who}") , method=RequestMethod.GET `or  `@GetMapping("/monohello/{who}") , method=RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: Thanks you. Have tried, but the same error response.

Comment: Does it actually make sense to accept a Mono as a method parameter?  You'd need to register a Converter that converts Sting -> Mono<String>.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is because spring can't find a registered `Converter<String,Mono<String>>`.  I'm not sure this is actually something you'd want to do though.  It's probably easiest to just create the Mono in the method.  You're not gaining much by using the converter in this case.  In fact, you're mainly just losing flexibility in how the Mono is created.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert

Comment: Thank you! After registering the converter, everything becomes cool.  But as you mentioned, it didn't make sense.  I just thought maybe spring-webflux already implemented these functions for us, not only the converters but also the json deserializers, ie., @RequestBody Mono<Sir>.